# Firefox is not shown as opened in the dock on 22.04

Tags: gnome, firefox, wayland, dock, 22.04

This is a screenshot of my dock bar on the left in Ubuntu 22.04:

[image]

There is a small green arrow on the left of the "Files" application because a nautilus window is actually opened.

But no such arrow is present nearby the Firefox icon, even so I do have a Firefox window which is opened. So, if I click on that icon, it tries to open a new Firefox window (without any success), where it should show up my already opened windows (which it actually doesn't).

Is there anything I can do to fix this? It seems to only happen with Firefox.

Info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 42.0

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

$ uname -mor
5.15.0-25-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

More:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It's probably because Firefox in 22.04 is packaged as a snap.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I can see this in the apt cache: `firefox - Transitional package - firefox -> firefox snap`. Is is then still possible to install and keep Firefox up-to-date using deb packages? That could be nice... * sigh *

Comment: Lots of questions on the site about that already.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-in-ubuntu-22-04-jammy/1404401#1404401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-in-ubuntu-22-04-jammy)

Comment: Although I voted for the same duplicate ^^^ it must be said that regardless of the packaging it should work as it always did. I'm running 22.04 with Firefox snap and it does show up as opened in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution is to:

1. Open Activities & search for Firefox
2. Drag the icon to the Dock again

This doesn’t appear to create a second icon, but it does seem to update the Dock so that it shows an indicator.

This problem appeared after upgrading from 20.04.

I’m not a big fan of forced snaps, but this isn’t my main PC, so minimising PPAs means less maintenance in the long run.